# Is it ever correct to say that $\vec{a}-\vec{a}=0$?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

My textbooks define $$\begin{cases}0\cdot \vec{a}=\vec{0}\\(m+n)\vec{a}=m\vec{a}+n\vec{a}\end{cases}$$ Therefore, $\vec{a}-\vec{a}=(1-1)\vec{a}=0\cdot\vec{a}=\vec{0}$.

> But is it ever acceptable, in some context, to claim that $\vec{a}-\vec{a}=0$?

Comment: It's perfectly okay to write this; it's just not okay to *mean* it.  Mathematicians will often denote a vector by a single letter (say $a$) without an arrow on top.  Then $0$ sometimes means the *number* zero and sometimes means the *vector* zero, depending on context.  As long as the context is clear, it's okay to write that way.  But if there's any ambiguity about the context --- or if you're a student who is just learning this stuff and so might not be incredibly sensitive to context yet --- then it's important to have different notations for the two zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, you're asking whether it's acceptable to write $0$ rather than $\vec 0$. Typically, no: the first is a scalar, while the second is a vector, and the addition of two vectors gives another vector.

There are other common notations for vectors, such as bold type (e.g, $\mathbf a - \mathbf a = \mathbf 0$ for all vectors $\mathbf a$), but one way or another you must make the distinction between scalar and vector.

Comment: That was a weird question in the first place. Making it possible to denote $\vec{a}-\vec{a}=0$ would imply $\vec{0}=0$, which doesn't make much sense. I guess I really shouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: @mathh Always ask weird questions; they give a person a huge advantage over the students who carry misconceptions for years without questioning them.  The lesson here, if there is one, should be only that you can be more confident in answering them without assistance.

Comment: If you think of a vector as a magnitude with direction (from a physics-like aspect), then isn't the zero vector a vector with zero magnitude thus no possible direction which means one can say that zero is equal to the zero vector?

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi if that's a question you want a serious answer to, then perhaps you should make a new post for that question.  The short answer is that this is one of the many circumstances in which the physics notion of a vector being "an object with direction and magnitude" fails.  There are other circumstances where intuitively tying each vector to a different "direction" might overcomplicate the situation or otherwise lead you astray.

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi For such vectors (e.g., in physics) it might be more appropriate to think of them as recording magnitude in each dimension: the zero vector is $0$ along the $x$-axis, $0$ along the $y$-axis, and so on. I would say that direction is a *property* of non-zero vectors, rather than part of the *definition* of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

$0$ usually denotes the neutral element whenever you are working in a (additive) group, like in this case.
It's just a short name for that (the zero vector $\vec{0}$) so as long as the context is clear, it's ok to use it.